# How do I get the request.user.id in serializer method field?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Here is my serializer method field:

```
def get_is_user_to_user(self, obj):
    return obj.to_user == self.context.get('request').user.id
```

I want the method to return a boolean value of `True` if `obj.to_user` which is a field in the corresponding model equals the `request.user.id`. The method field at the moment always returns `False` even when it should be returning `True`.

How do I check if `obj.to_user` is equal to the `request.user.id` from the serializer method field?

Comment: Can you add more information about the question. Also try this: `obj.to_user.id == self.context.get('request').user.id`

Comment: That is the exact same thing as in my question

Comment: not exactly, look more closely.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_is_user_to_user(self, obj):
    return obj.to_user == self.context.get('request').user.id
```

I think your FK `obj.to_user` is a User instance, you can not compare with `self.context.get('request').user.id`.

Your code should:

```
def get_is_user_to_user(self, obj):
    return obj.to_user.id == self.context.get('request').user.id
```

Or:

```
def get_is_user_to_user(self, obj):
    return obj.to_user == self.context.get('request').user # Make sure you did not override request.user before.
```

Answer (score 0):

I used below Sample View

```py
class CurrentUserView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(request.user)
        return Response({"user": serializer.data})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you mind including some text explaining your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method i user model then use at as a field

E.g.:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    def chechsomething(self):
        if something :
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).